# MonoDevelop 7.8 always fail to build

Tags: windows, mono, monodevelop

I have created an .NET C# application with VisualStudio. Now i would like to make the app run on Mac and Linux too. Since the app is very simple and only uses a few graphical elements i thought i could port this easily to a mono apllication with gtk.

Therefore i have downloaded MonoDevelop for windows as a prebuilt archive. 
After starting monodevelop i have tried to create a test application.

I have did that by: File->NewSolution->GTK#2.0 Project
Then i have choosed .net 4.71 as .NET Version. All of my References looks good (they are not grayed out) but

```
 using system;
 using Gtk;
```

is always red.

If i try to build the project then i get:

```
 Building test (Debug|x86)


 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped      ==========

 Build failed.
 Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

The log-file is also empty.

[image]

[image]

I hope, someone could give me some hints, where to debug this problem.

by the way, is there any other way to achieve my goal to make my application runable on mac and linux? I dont want to use java etc.

Thanks

Comment: this is a bug in monodevelop, please report it on github

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the official MonoDevelop 7.8 source code, so a few patches are needed on Windows.

I have a fork with such patches on GitHub,

https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop/commits/ac67534eb543228cac470ade2923f7bc107425ce

And you might use the MSI installer to install it,

https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows/releases